# Plotting an array in histogram style without using hist function in Python with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

How do i plot an array in a histogram style using matplotlib.plot() or similar functions?

I also use scikit as a package but im completely new to that one and have not found an alternative there either so far.

The function hist in matplotlib calculates the histogram (e.g. of a picture) and plots it. However, for my assignment i have to calculate the histogram myself as an array of shape (256,), where each index corresponds to a calculated grey-scale value from 0 to 255.

So far i looked at the different parameters of matplotlib.plot() but could not see or figure out a way to plot in a hist style.

Comment: I am sure you can calculate your histogram with the [keywords provided by matplotlib hist](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html), e.g., the bin parameter.

Comment: @Mr.T the bins parameter lets you choose your resolution. If you set it to 256 in my case, you will get a bin for each value, reduce it to 128 and 2 bins will be merged together reducing resolution. However, i still would like to use my own calculated array, which i cant when i use hist. Using my array with hist would yield me a histogram of my histogram.

Comment: `bins: int or sequence or str` - it takes an array, if that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try calculating the histogram and than plotting this as [bars](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html)?

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

dummie_data = np.random.randint(0, 256, (100,100))

values, count = np.unique(dummie_data, return_counts=True)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.bar(values, count/dummie_data.size, width=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

By using:

```py
plt.bar(values, count, width=1)
```

You use the absolute frequency.

Comment: Thank you very much, thats exactly what i needed.